# How to insert sql data in a certain format in an excel file?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, excel

So I'm sure all of you know what a wage report is, it's basically a piece of paper where you write how many hours you worked that day and how much you are making per hour and then you sign a date. So I have an excel version of a physical wage report and I want to be able to take the data from an SQL server and insert it certain pieces of data in certain cells in the excel sheet, because it needs to be put in a certain format. I already know how you can just insert the data from the SQL server into a table in an excel file, but my question is how do I do it if I need the info from SQL displayed in a certain way on the excel sheet.

I haven't tried anything, because I've been searching for a way to do this, but I've come up with nothing. I'm having a hard time knowing where to start, if this is even possible at all.

Comment: dump sql data into a table on a separate tab > write formulas in your wage report to pull data from the table

Comment: You just have to do it. Get the data into a table like you know how to do (in a different sheet), then use formulas like `=TableSheetA1` and `=TableSheetC5` to point to the data you need. You can get more fancy than that, but that's about as helpful as we can be without knowing your data, the forms layout, or the requirements.

Comment: This question is entirely too broad for an online forum. It sounds like you want a tutorial. That makes it off topic for SO.

Comment: I am not clear on what you are trying to do are you generating a workbook per employee for a period of time for them  to complete?

Comment: Excel can load data from any database and format it, pivot it, summarize and visualize it any way you want it without writing a single line of code. It even has themes you can apply to your tables. Perhaps you should look for an Excel tutorial?

Comment: Alright thanks for the info guys, honestly I just wanted some confirmation on if it was even possible, because I was trying to google for this but had a hard time coming up with something. Thanks for the help!